# Implement function overloading in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working on the problem for writing Haskell code similar to a C++ program.

The C++ code is:

```
class Rectangle
{
    private:
        int length;
        int width;
    public:
        Rectangle()
        {
            length = 0;
            width = 0;
        }
        Rectangle(int x)
        {
            length = x;
            width =0;
        }
        Rectangle ( int x , int y)
        {
            length = x;
            width = y;
        }
};
```

To write similar Haskell code i made a data type Rectangle

```
data Rectangle = Rectangle Length Width deriving (Eq, Show , Read)
type Length = Int
type Width = Int
```

Then i thought of making a load function which can act as constructor. But i don't understand how to implement function overloading with different number of arguments. 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to model haskell after C++; it will just lead to a lot of pain. Also, why is your second rectangle constructor a line? I think a more sensible implementation would be to default to (1, 1), and if you get one int, pass in (x, x), to form a square.

Comment: Ever heard of constructor initialization list?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Ever heard of people who are still learning? (Hint: You are among them, everyone is)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While it *is* possible to do such overloading in Haskell, it's not considered idiomatic, and will likely lead to confusing errors later on. Instead, you should simply define functions that construct data:

```
point :: Rectangle
point = Rectangle 0 0

line :: Length -> Rectangle
line l = Rectangle l 0

square :: Int -> Rectangle
square a = Rectangle a a
```

This allows you to give clear names that describe the *semantics* of each overloading, rather than relying on the number and type of arguments given to disambiguate which you mean.

However, if you do want to write the overloaded version, you can do it easily with typeclasses:

```
class MakeRectangle a where
  rectangle :: a

instance MakeRectangle Rectangle where
  rectangle = Rectangle 0 0

instance MakeRectangle (Length -> Rectangle) where
  rectangle l = Rectangle l 0

instance MakeRectangle (Length -> Width -> Rectangle) where
  rectangle = Rectangle
```

You'll need `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` at the top of your file to compile this. A trick like this is used by the standard [`Text.Printf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Printf.html) library, but I would not consider it a particularly good example of overloading in Haskell; there is almost always some structure to the overloaded value's type, whereas here its entire structure is dictated by the instance, which can get in the way of type inference; not only that, but there aren't any reasonable laws that govern instances (indeed, the type is too general to permit any).

But if you really want to do it, you can, and while it's usually a bad idea, sometimes (as in the case of `printf`) it's the only way to accomplish the interface you want.

To try this out in GHCi, you'll need to specify the types you're using explicitly, or it won't be able to resolve the instances:

```
GHCi> rectangle :: Rectangle
Rectangle 0 0
GHCi> rectangle (1 :: Length) :: Rectangle
Rectangle 1 0
GHCi> rectangle (1 :: Length) (2 :: Width) :: Rectangle
Rectangle 1 2
```

Comment: I am not able to compile the program. Error is `multiple declarations for rectangle`

Comment: Did you make sure to preserve the indentation? Do you have another declaration of `rectangle` elsewhere in the file? If it's neither of those, then add the full file you're compiling to your question and I'll take a look.

Comment: You forgot to include the spaces from my code; Haskell is an indentation-sensitive language.

Comment: Can u explain that what happens with or without space?

Comment: Without the spaces, the definitions of `rectangle` given are taken as duplicate top-level definitions, and the `class` and `instance` definitions are empty; with the spaces, the definitions of `rectangle` are associated with the `class` and `instance` declarations as intended.

Answer (score 22):

You can use record syntax to reach that behavior.

```
data Rectangle = Rectangle {len :: Length, width :: Width} deriving (Eq, Show , Read)
type Length = Int
type Width = Int

rectangle = Rectangle { len = 0, width = 0 }
```

`rectangle :: Rectangle` will be your constructor here.

Now you can define some `Rectangle` values:

```
λ> let a = rectangle {len = 1}

λ> a
Rectangle {len = 1, width = 0}
```

Answer (score 4):

Isn't what you are looking for simply this:

```
data Rectangle = Point |  Line Int | Rectangle Int Int
```